# How do I get the value off the spinbox in ttk?

Tags: python, ttk

I now have a working spinbox, but I can't find out how to get the value of the spinbox. When looking on the internet I couldn't get the examples working, can someone help?

This is what I now have.

```
spinbox = StringVar()
s = ttk.Spinbox(root, from_=1.0, to=100.0, textvariable=spinbox).grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(root, text="amount:").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
```

Just having the number get printed in the console is good enough.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `SpinBox.grid()` doesn't return anything i.e. returns `None`.

So do it this way:

```py
s = ttk.Spinbox(root, from_=1.0, to=100.0, textvariable=spinbox)
s.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=W)
print(s.get())
```

Edit-
Add a function to get the value and add that function to command parameter

```
def get_spinbox_val():
    global s
    print(s.get())

s = ttk.Spinbox(root, from_=1.0, to=100.0, textvariable=spinbox, command=get_spinbox_val)
s.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=W)
```

Comment: How should I use `s.get()`? When I try to use it I get this error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working, now I still have the spinbox, but nothing still nothing happens with the number that's used...

Comment: What's the value that you are getting? Could you paste some screenshots of the same?

Comment: Salva, if it is to me, then here is my answer. I don't get any numbers back anywhere, the number goes up on my screen in the spinbox, but it doesn't sent it anywhere in de console or anything...

Comment: Ohh, could you add some screenshots? Or a gif?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nB4R6D1.gif
I use r instead of s here because I already used s, but in both cases it does not work. I hope the gif is good enough, if not, just tell me and I'll make a better one.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Try debugging it or if possible send the link of the GitHub repo of this.

Comment: here is the GitHub repo, I hope I did it all correct since this is my first real repo. I am dutch, so sorry for any Dutch words that are in the code. https://github.com/LFGaming/color-screen

Comment: I got it. The print statement was only being executed once. So I created a callback function for that and also have sent you a pull request with the changes

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help, I’ll let you know if it works all correct when I am able to test it behind my computer.

Comment: Yupp sure! It worked on my system so apparently, it should work in yours too

Comment: It all work correct :) thanks allot.
should I now approve the question or not? I am new, I am not sure

Comment: Yes you can if you want. Your choice

Comment: I mean, the awnser above is not right, but in the comments it is resolved. what sould i do then?

Comment: I corrected it now. So you can approve it

Comment: My pleasure bro!

Comment: You can upvote it too. So it will stay on top for others

Comment: I am sorry I can't yet, I do not have 15 reputation point... I'll do when I can